# Can I install FIFA 14 on Lumia 520 with Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, games

Can I install FIFA 14 on my phone, running Windows Phone version 8.1?

Comment: If you try to find it in the Store in your phone and you have free space to install (more than the download size),  yes, you could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FIFA 14 requires a Windows Phone with 1GB of RAM to run, so unfortunately **the Lumia 520 will not run this game**.

If you search for FIFA 14 in the Store app, it won't show up as games or apps that require 1GB of RAM are hidden.

If you happen to open a [direct link to the game](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/fifa-14/0ed6989b-5cb9-4b70-a58b-536c0dce36b2?device=6ACD13243544DF90A35B89E4E844F7244EC79B121CAFE1455A8C652A0225A06B), either on your phone or via the Windows Phone website, you should see a message saying...

> Your phone doesn't meet the minimum requirements needed to run this
>   app.

Comment: yup that was the same thing i got online on pc

Comment: @agharehanabbas EA may update the game to work with 512MB devices, but we have no way of knowing if that will ever happen.